# How to call the mainwindow object from a second object created from main window in c# .net

Tags: c#, winforms

Being a very first user in Windows Form Development I want to ask a simple question ...

I created a form(MainWindow.cs) within the solution which opens at the time of running that solution.

Latter I created a second form(SecondWindow.cs) and created a event so that it can be called from the first window by clicking a button.When the second window loded up the first window(MainWindow.cs) will be disabled.

Now I want to enable the MainWindow.cs when the second window is closed.

How to do That...

A simple solution I already have is to hide the MainWindow.cs and latter on closing the second window make a new object of first window and show it.But it is not a good way i think because there is already a object created by .net framework for first window automatically, so why we should create a new object of Mainwindow.cs .

Code Of First Window ( MainWindow.cs ) :

```
private void priceControllToolStripMenuItem_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
       SecondWindow price = new SecondWindow();
        this.Enabled = false;
        price.Show();
    }
```

Code Of Second Window ( On closing SecondWindow.cs )

```
private void price_controll_FormClosed(object sender, FormClosedEventArgs e)
    {
        // what will goes here to make the MainWindow.cs to enable state
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can pass the main form as an owner to the second form

```
private void priceControllToolStripMenuItem_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    SecondWindow price = new SecondWindow() { Owner = this };
    this.Enabled = false;
    price.Show();
}
```

Then you can reference it from the second form.

```
private void price_controll_FormClosed(object sender, FormClosedEventArgs e)
{
    Owner.Enabled = true;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Use `price.ShowDialog()` to show second form as modal dialog. Main form will be disabled until you close second form:

```
private void priceControllToolStripMenuItem_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    using(SecondWindow price = new SecondWindow())
        price.ShowDialog();
}
```

Comment: Thanks ... it is working ... but my question is yet not solved .Can I call the Mainwindow's object from second form. and what is the main window's object's name created automatically by .net framework

Comment: @ShyamaprasadPatra there is no direct variable by default created for main application form. If you will look at `Program.cs` you will see `Application.Run(new MainWindow());`. You can store reference to main window here. Also you can get MainWindow instance from application opened forms collection `var form = Application.OpenForms[0];`. But usually you do opposite thing - create event on second form and subscribe to that event in main form. When something happened on second form event handler on main form will be invoked.